# What is $2^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot4^{\frac{1}{8}}\cdot8^{\frac{1}{16}}\cdot16^{\frac{1}{32}}\cdots\infty$ equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, infinite-product

I came across this question while doing my homework:

> $$\Large 2^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot4^{\frac{1}{8}}\cdot8^{\frac{1}{16}}\cdot16^{\frac{1}{32}}\cdots\infty=?$$

$$\small\text{OR}$$

$$\large\prod\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} (2x)^{\frac{1}{4x}} = ?$$

---

**My Attempt:**

$\large 2^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot4^{\frac{1}{8}}\cdot8^{\frac{1}{16}}\cdot16^{\frac{1}{32}}\cdots\infty$

$\large \Rightarrow 2^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot2^{\frac{2}{8}}\cdot2^{\frac{3}{16}}\cdot2^{\frac{4}{32}}\cdots\infty$

$\large \Rightarrow 2^{(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{8} + \frac{3}{16} + \cdots \infty)}$

OR, $\large 2^{\space (\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{2^{x+1}})}$

$\cdots$ That's it ... I am stuck here ... It does not resemble any series I know...

---

> *How do you do it? **Thanks!***

Comment: The title as well as the bold statement at the beginning of the question say $\prod$. The statement under the "OR" says $\sum$.

Comment: @barakmanos Sorry...editing now!

Comment: @NeilRoy Hey! the term doesn't go to infinity, it tends to one instead.  Use proper notation!

Comment: @NgChungTak What do you mean?

Comment: @NeilRoy I've help you editing more formally, why you wasted all my works?

Comment: @NgChungTak It doesn't tend to 1 ... it tends to infinity . Read the question again! The answer may tend to 1...but the question is for terms as in 2,4,8,16,...$\infty$

Comment: @NgChungTak You still don't get the "Question". Look at the answers below ... the sum tends to $\infty$ ... Its the same

Comment: $1024^{1/2048}=1.003390242$,$2048^{1/4096}=1.001863213$

Comment: @NgChungTak You still not getting my question? Read it CAREFULLY.
The answer may be 1 but the sequence tends to go on

Comment: @NeilRoy I'm trying to help you.  What I'm saying is $\infty$ is redundant, just keeping $\ldots$ is good enough.  Coz $\infty^{0}$ is indeterminate form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Olympiad Tricks**
\begin{align*}
  y &=
  1^{\frac{1}{2}} \times 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \times 4^{\frac{1}{8}} \times
  \ldots \times 2^{\frac{n-1}{2^{n}}} \times \ldots \\[3pt]
  y^{2} &= 
  2^{\frac{1}{2}} \times 4^{\frac{1}{4}} \times 8^{\frac{1}{8}} \times
  \ldots \times 2^{\frac{n}{2^{n}}} \times \ldots \\[3pt]
  \frac{y^{2}}{y} &=
  \frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}} \times 4^{\frac{1}{4}} \times 8^{\frac{1}{8}} \times
  \ldots \times 2^{\frac{n}{2^{n}}} \times \ldots}
       {1^{\frac{1}{2}} \times 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \times 4^{\frac{1}{8}} \times
  \ldots \times 2^{\frac{n-1}{2^{n}}} \times \ldots} \\[3pt]
  y &=
  2^{\frac{1}{2}} \times 2^{\frac{1}{4}} \times 2^{\frac{1}{8}} \times
  \ldots \times 2^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}} \times \ldots \\[3pt]
  &=2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\ldots} \\[3pt]
  &=2^{1} \\[3pt]
  &=2
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks buddy! This is the best method!

Answer (score 5):

The only thing left that we have to do is to evaluate the following infinite sum:

$$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{2^{x+1}}$$

Dividing by $2$ would gives us $$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{2^{x+2}}=\sum\limits_{x=2}^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{2^{x+1}}$$

Now, subtract this from the original equation. The limit should now not be too hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

For every $x\in \mathbb R$ which $|x|\lt 1$, we have: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ From here: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$ Now, multiplying $x^2$ in both side we get that: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n+1}=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}$$ And so: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}=1$$

Comment: I am sorry...but how do you get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n+1}=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}$ ? Thanks!

Comment: @NeilRoy: $$|x|<1\implies\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)'=\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$and now just multiply both sides by $\;x^2\;$